# Angular/RxJS Unsubscribe from previous request

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am trying to find a more efficient/rxjs-ish way to accomplish this. The code below works, but there has to be a better way.

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(({ bookId }) => {
    this.characters$ && this.characters$.unsubscribe();

    this.characters$ = this.fetchCharactersByBook(bookId)
      .subscribe(characters => this.characters = characters);
  });
}
```

Essentially what I am just listening for a change to the route params and subscribing to a request to fetch `Characters` by `bookId`. With each change to the route params I need to initially unsubscribe from the previous request to fetch characters.

Is there a better, more elegant way to accomplish this?

Sometimes RxJS makes my head swirl with all of the operators. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[switchMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/switchmap.html) can be used to switch from the outer observable to the inner observable, and has the advantages of *unsubscribing* to the inner observable when the next value is emitted. Unsubscribing will cancel the previous Http requests that are still pending.

You can use `*ngIf="o$ | async as o"` syntax in the template to avoid having to subscribe and assign the variable to a local property. `as o` will declare a template variable with the emitted value.

You can use [shareReplay](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/multicasting/sharereplay.html) if you want to use `o$ | async` multiple times in the same template without making multiple Http requests.

```js
@Component({
   ...
   template: `<ng-container *ngIf="characters$ | async as characters">
      {{characters | json}}
   </ng-container>`
})
export class ExampleComponent {
   characters$: Observable<Character[]>;

   public ngOnInit() {
      this.characters$ = this.activatedRoute.params.pipe(
         pluck('bookId'),
         switchMap(bookId => this.fetchCharactersByBook(bookId)),
         shareReplay(1)
      );
   }
}
```

Comment: I'm a reactive noob, but is `shareReplay(1)` really necessary? Shouldn't the API call only happen when `activatedRoute.params` emits regardless of use in the template?

Comment: @TheHeadRush the API call happens only when code *subscribes*. Nothing happens if param emits a value and nothing is subscribed. If there are *two* subscribers, then there will be *two* http requests. Unless both subscribers use the same observable that has a shareReplay. It will multicast the last emitted value from the first subscriber.

Comment: @TheHeadRush my code example only has one `async` pipe. So it's not necessary in that example. Generally, you don't need it. If you place a `ng-container` at the top of the template the way I did, then there is usually only one subscriber.

Comment: For some reason, I thought you were saying the template's change detection loop would cause multiple API calls without `shareReplay`.  Got it now.

Comment: @TheHeadRush that can happen if you use a function in a template that returns a new observable. Which has been asked here many times as bugs, because Angular calls the function on every change loop which creates a new observable which starts a new subscriber and a Http call is made. `shareReplay` won't help in that case because it's a new observable each time.

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need to `unsubscribe`. You could instead transform the params object to the character list using the `switchMap` operator. And you should manage the subscription imperatively by unwrapping it in the template with the `async` pipe.

Create your character observable.

```
this.characters$ = this.activatedRoute.params
  .pipe(switchMap(parms => this.fetchCharactersByBook(parms.bookId));
```

Once the `observable` is created, use the async pipe to unwrap it by replacing template references to `characters` with `(characters$ | async)`. The component will dispose of the `characters$` observable as part of the tear down process.\